# How can I implement static cache in rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to implement a static cache in rust.

I tried [chashmap](https://docs.rs/chashmap/2.2.2/chashmap/)

```rust
extern crate chashmap;
extern crate lazy_static;
use chashmap::{CHashMap, ReadGuard};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Data {}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Merged {
    types: HashMap<String, Data>,
}

fn merge(ls: &[String]) -> ReadGuard<'static, Vec<String>, Merged> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref CACHE: CHashMap<Vec<String>, Merged> = Default::default();
    }

    let libs = ls.to_vec();

    let merged = Merged::default();

    CACHE.insert(libs, merged);

    return CACHE.get(ls).unwrap();
}

fn get<'a>(ls: &[String], name: &str) -> Option<&'a Data> {
    let lib = merge(ls);

    if let Some(ty) = lib.types.get(name) {
        return Some(&*ty);
    }

    None
}

fn main() {}
```

```
[package]
name = "stackoverflow-56728860"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["강동윤 <kdy1@outlook.kr>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
lazy_static = "1"
chashmap = "2"
```

[github repo](https://github.com/kdy1/stackoverflow-56728860)

But I want to return static reference to data from the function. The returned data solely depends on `ls`. That is, if input (`ls`) is same, the result would be same.

Also, leaking data is ok if read lock is released.

Comment: @Stargateur I tried to create it on play.rust-lang.org, but chashmap is not available from there. I'll create a new repository.

Comment: @Stargateur I added it.

Comment: you obviously can't return the data without keep the rearguard alive

Comment: maybe https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b719a81aa334921c144617a10b51f80, but it's unclear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow solved it with leaking.

```
fn merge(ls: &[Lib]) -> &'static Merged {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref CACHE: CHashMap<Vec<Lib>, &'static Merged> = Default::default();
    }

    // ...

    CACHE.insert(libs, Box::leak(merged));

    return &*CACHE.get(ls).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: There's one problem here: you leak even if the `insert` fails. Do you really want to leak every time this function is called?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't care leaking on each compilation, but leaking on insertion failure seems problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately, `CHashMap` does not seem to have a method to insert only if things do not exist; any `insert` replaces the previous value :/